# new Date(date).getTime(); to read time in d/m/y format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datatable

EDIT:
I created an example of what I am trying to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/HvItQP2uDooaMgK7GRQe?p=preview

There are several problems with it.

1. It does not work in FF (on MAC). No errors that I can see.
2. In chrome after selecting 11-04-17 to 17-04-17 It still shows rows with 30/03/2017

I really appreciate everyone's help and again please keep in mind I just started with JS last week. I can read the code and (possibly) understand the logic, but I am not on the level where I can clearly see how to implement it.

---

I am using datatables to sort some basic data by dates. There was an excellent example [here:](http://plnkr.co/edit/mdeEYoZtnvpfHCdtSxDP?p=preview) that I copied. The example dates are in mm/dd/yyyy format.

I need it to run in dd/mm/yyyy. When I switch the dates in the example to the format I need it no longer works.

I am very new to JS so I imagine this is the part that does the magic:

```
 minDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
```

minDateFilter grabs the data in the input, and .getTime() converts it to seconds from 1970. I googled around if I can get it to start with day something like 
.getTime(dateFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy") but no luck yet.

If anyone could help me out here I'd appreciate it. I can always use a hidden field but rather not.

Thank you

Comment: I don't see `minDateFilter` in the example that you linked to?

Comment: @Xotic750 It is in script.js, look at menu on the left.

Comment: use https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Are your date strings UTC or local?

Comment: And be specific, you want `dd/mm/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yy` date format?

Comment: @gotz  - Thank you looks like a viable solution, althought I want to limit how many libraries I add to this soup. If I can't solve the issue I will default to moments

Comment: @Xotic - I did not even consider this. Thank you for pointing it out. Since I am in SEA it would make sense to use local time. Now another variable to research.

Comment: @Oen - From what I can tell it does not matter since I experimented with 16 and 2016. I think yyyy would make more sense from a user point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string and then parse that into [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).
Depending on UTC you will get a different value in ms back (unless you happen to be a GMT timezone). In your case where you are just using this for the sorting reference, it should not matter which value you use, as long as you use the same type for all of them.

```js
function getTime(value, utc) {
  // with dd/mm/yyyy then part[0] will be dd,
  // part[1] will be mm and part[2] will be yyyy
  var parts = value.split('/');
  // Date requires a zero referenced month
  parts[1] -= 1;
  if (utc) {
    return Date.UTC(parts[2], parts[1], parts[0]);
  }
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1], parts[0]).getTime();
}
var value = '03/03/2016';
console.log(getTime(value));
console.log(getTime(value, true));
```

Update: This is beyond your actual question, and as such is no longer on topic. However, answer merged with your code, no warranty. There are also plugins available, which include `moments`, if you don't want to do this yourself.

```js
var getTime = function(value, utc) {
  // with dd/mm/yyyy then part[0] will be dd,
  // part[1] will be mm and part[2] will be yyyy
  var parts = value.split('/');
  // Date requires a zero referenced month
  parts[1] -= 1;
  if (utc) {
    return Date.UTC(parts[2], parts[1], parts[0]);
  }
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1], parts[0]).getTime();
};

var types = $.fn.dataTable.ext.type;

// Add type detection
types.detect.unshift(function(d) {
  var ms = getTime(d);
  var isValid = typeof ms === 'number' && !isNaN(ms);
  return isValid ? 'date-x' : null;
});

// Add sorting method - use an integer for the sorting
types.order['date-x-pre'] = function(d) {
  return getTime(d);
};

// Date range filter
var minDateFilter = '';
var maxDateFilter = '';

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
  function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    if (typeof aData._date === 'undefined') {
      aData._date = getTime(aData[0]);
    }

    if (minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter)) {
      if (aData._date < minDateFilter) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    if (maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter)) {
      if (aData._date > maxDateFilter) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
);

var oTable = $('#datatable').DataTable({
  oLanguage: {
    sSearch: 'Filter Data'
  },
  iDisplayLength: -1,
  sPaginationType: 'full_numbers'
});

$('#datepicker_from').datepicker({
  showOn: 'button',
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  buttonImageOnly: false,
  onSelect: function(date) {
    minDateFilter = getTime(date);
    oTable.draw();
  }
}).keyup(function() {
  minDateFilter = getTime(this.value);
  oTable.draw();
});

$('#datepicker_to').datepicker({
  showOn: 'button',
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  buttonImageOnly: false,
  onSelect: function(date) {
    maxDateFilter = getTime(date);
    oTable.draw();
  }
}).keyup(function() {
  maxDateFilter = getTime(this.value);
  oTable.draw();
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<p id="date_filter">
  <span id="date-label-from" class="date-label">From: </span><input class="date_range_filter date" type="text" id="datepicker_from" />
  <span id="date-label-to" class="date-label">To:</span><input class="date_range_filter date" type="text" id="datepicker_to" />
</p>
<table width="100%" class="display" id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>30/03/2017</td>
      <td><a href="42296/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000617 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>30/03/2017</td>
      <td><a href="42297/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000618 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>30/03/2017</td>
      <td><a href="42298/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000619 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>03/04/2017</td>
      <td><a href="42340/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000620 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>03/04/2017</td>
      <td><a href="42343/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000621 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>03/04/2017</td>
      <td><a href="42344/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000622 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>03/04/2017</td>
      <td><a href="42345/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000623 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>03/04/2017</td>
      <td><a href="42348/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000624 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>03/04/2017</td>
      <td><a href="42350/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000625 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>04/04/2017</td>
      <td><a href="42395/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000626 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>05/04/2017</td>
      <td><a href="42427/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000627 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>05/04/2017</td>
      <td><a href="42446/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000628 </a></td>
      <tr>
        <td>05/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42458/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000629 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>05/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42461/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000630 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>06/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42490/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000631 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>06/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42491/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000632 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>06/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42493/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000633 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>06/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42494/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000634 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>06/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42497/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000635 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>07/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42531/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000636 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>07/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42532/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000637 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>07/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42533/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000638 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>07/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42539/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000640 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>07/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42540/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000641 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>07/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42541/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000642 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>07/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42542/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000643 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>07/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42544/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000644 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>08/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42565/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000645 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>08/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42566/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000646 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42604/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000647 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42607/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000648 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42636/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000649 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42638/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000650 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42639/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000651 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42661/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000652 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42664/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000653 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42711/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000654 </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15/04/2017</td>
        <td><a href="42712/service_request/CS_Reviewed" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">000000655 </a></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, again I am a newb so please bare with me.
What you are doing with this formula is converting the dd/mm/yyyy format of my table to the milliseconds, correct?

You split the original date into parts and feed that into the formula that will sort by date.

If I understand that correct, please help me out with the following:

1. You wrote if UTC statement, how does UTC factor into this whole formula? Do I need to specify use server time or user computer time? 

2. I made http://plnkr.co/edit/HvItQP2uDooaMgK7GRQe?p=preview how would you integrate your code into this

Comment: Thank you. I did find an app that does exactly what I want: http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html What I am trying to achieve is to go beyond using other people's work and managing to write some of my own code. You and other good devs are a great help to those of us who are stuck on an issue and are ready to flip the computer over. Great to see how to solve your problem coming from a pro

Answer (score 3):

`getTime` returns unix timestamp in seconds, not date like `17/04/2017`. You will have to use `toLocalDateString`.

```js
var date = new Date();

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("en-GB"));
```

Comment: `I need it to run in dd/mm/yyyy.`, he doesn't want `yy` format.

Comment: hes actually saying two things: *getTime(dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy")* i mean the month...

Comment: `"oen44s:17/04/2017"` that's what I see, and it's fine. And yeah, he did say two date formats...

Comment: Fixed! Now it's shorter too.

Comment: Sorry a bit confused, that just converts the todays date, to the format I need. But I have the opposite problem, I need the format I need to be converted to be understood by the formula. How does this work in my case?

Answer (score 1):

```
d = new Date(date);
f=d=>(d+"").length==2?""+d:"0"+d;
minDateFilter= f(d.getDate())+"-"+f(d.getMonth()+1)+"-"+f(d.getYear()%100);
```

http://jsbin.com/sosurohaje/edit?console

Explanation:

d.getDate returns the day of the month,

d.getMonth returns the month from 0-11 (thats why the +1 )

.getYear returns the year from 1900, thats why i used modulo 100 to format it:

```
2014 => 114 %100 => 14
1914 => 14 %100 => 14
2000 => 100 % 100 => 0
```

And thanks to oen44 ive included a function *f* that will add a leading 0 if it isnt a two digit number...

Comment: That's not going to be `dd/mm/yyyy` format, `getMonth` returns 0-11, without leading zero.

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't follow this at all. I am sure it makes sense to a seasoned pro, but on my level even with the explanation you provided it does not.

Comment: @user2542080 oh after reading your edit, i think ive missunderstood your question. my code does the opposite, it translates a date into dd-mm-yy format... have a look at Xotics answer, it provides the only solution for you. The utc factor parses the time as UTC or as local users time...

Comment: @Jonasw I should have wrote a clearer request. Thank you for taking your time to answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have the date Object and you know the output format you can construct the output string with the date methods, in example:

```
var date = new Date("05/26/1984");
var formatDate = curdate.getDate() + "/" + (curdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + curdate.getFullYear();
```

If the problem is the input you can get the day, month and year with split and create de date with "new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)":

```
var input = "26/05/1984";
var aux = input.split("/");
var day =aux[0];
var month = aux[1];
var year = aux[2];
var date = new Date(year,month - 1,day,0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: My second option is like @Xotic750, but he forgot the "-1" on month field. If the purpose is just ordering this is not a problem, so his answer is the right one.

Comment: When I started my answer the other one doesn't existed, so I read it after I post mine.