# Datatables sort date (d/m/Y H:i A)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatable

I am still new to datatables. I have a date formatted like this **01/10/2011 10:10 AM** and i want to sort it. I have read about the plugins available but i still can't manage to sort it correctly since it only sort based on date not month and year.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="datatables/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/sorting/date-euro.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test').dataTable({
            "columnDefs": [{
            "type": "date-euro",
            targets: 1
          }]
        });
    });

  </script>
<?php $filetime  = date("d/m/Y H:i A",filemtime($dir.'/'.$basename)); ?>

<table id="test">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Date Modified</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><?php echo $filetime; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: A similar question/example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43448024/new-datedate-gettime-to-read-time-in-d-m-y-format

Comment: Try custom sorting function in that case https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML5 Data Attributes. https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html

Just add the data-order element to your td element.

```
  <table class="table" id="exampleTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Date Modified</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td data-order="<?php echo date( "Y-m-d H:i", strtotime( $filetime) ); // PHP:  2015-11-13 12:00; ?>"><?php echo $filetime; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#exampleTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: but it still sort according to the date only. not month and year and i want it to be d/m/Y H:i A

Comment: @Athira have you check this example??

https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html

Comment: Okay i understand now. But i did some changes. i defined $filetime without  converting the date to d/m/Y H:i A. and based on your example, it supposed to be $filetime on data-order and when it echo inside the <td> tag, then it converts from string to time. do edit for other user's revision. Thank You.

Comment: but does data-order supported on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

DataTables doesn't seem to include the `date-euro` type by default, so make sure you included [the definition](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-euro) somewhere in your code:

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-euro-pre": function ( a ) {
        var x;

        if ( $.trim(a) !== '' ) {
            var frDatea = $.trim(a).split(' ');
            var frTimea = (undefined != frDatea[1]) ? frDatea[1].split(':') : [00,00,00];
            var frDatea2 = frDatea[0].split('/');
            x = (frDatea2[2] + frDatea2[1] + frDatea2[0] + frTimea[0] + frTimea[1] + frTimea[2]) * 1;
        }
        else {
            x = Infinity;
        }

        return x;
    },

    "date-euro-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return a - b;
    },

    "date-euro-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return b - a;
    }
} );
```